# Hardhat-deploy error

Tags: hardhat-deploy, typescript

[image]Help me figure out how to install and use hardhat-deploy. After installing it, I add to the hardhat.config.ts file, the line - import "hardhat-deploy"; And when running a node - npx hardhat node, I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length'). If I remove this line from hardhat.config.ts, the terminal does not recognize the command - npx hardhat deploy --network localhost, after starting the node. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: I added the picture

Answer (score 0):

To begin with you should add localhost network to your config which is the default hardhat network. in addition you should add this to your hardhat config:(the main reason)

```
namedAccounts:{
  deployer:{
    default:0
  }
}
```

Furthermore you could use the file naming convention in the deploy folder as official docs said: `000_*.ts`

Last but not least you could install hardhat shorthand command to getting ride of `npx hardhat` haha..

If it's useful please vote it up :)

Comment: 0xbeny means for the last part, that you can add a `scripts` entry to `package.json`, say `compile` that is `npx hardhat compile` meaning you can now just run `npm run compile`.  Obviously not much saving but would be more useful for something like `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`.